# HttpWebRequest.Create returns (500) Internal Server Error

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, httpwebrequest

It works fine to browse this page : http://www.litteraturmagazinet.se/arga-bibliotekstanten/boklogg/favorit-i-repris-9560835 in a regular browser(for example Chrome).

But when I use the following code to fetch the website I get Internal Server Error (500)?

This is the code I use (and it works great on all other webpages I have tried) :

```
HttpWebRequest request;
WebResponse webresponse;
request = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(url);
webresponse = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
```

The exception is thrown in GetResponse.

I have found for example this : [HttpWebRequest.GetResponse() returns error 500 Internal Server Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6516647/httpwebrequest-getresponse-returns-error-500-internal-server-error), but I do not understand it? Why does not request.GetResponse work with this specific webpage? And How do I know what to put in the header(It would be great if it dident hade to be updated later on to diffrent versions)?

Comment: What exception is `GetResponse()` throwing?

Comment: 500 is as good as any other response. If you think server should be returning something different - figure out what it expect and construct request appropriately. One way is to use Fiddler and make sure you request is exactly the same as one sent by a browser.

Comment: Side note: Are you really getting that exception from `Create` call? That is very strange as `Create` should not be making any outgoing calls...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I tried your url with wfetch with no headers and i get a 500 as well.

you have to set a proper user-agent in the headers of your request.

```
HttpWebRequest myHttpWebRequest=(HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://www.contoso.com");
myHttpWebRequest.UserAgent=".NET Framework Test Client";
```

Comment: Seems like setting any agent fixes it, i used: UserAgent = "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 5.01; Windows NT 5.0)";